# Solution for Routing while we make custom url and it affects css, images and links

Tags: css, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter independently first time for my personal project for practice.

I have created controller class and some other methods in that also created custom url using route.php i.e. as follwed:

```
$route['cele-saree'] = "celeSaree_c";
```

(`"celeSaree_c"` is my controller class index and I am making url as cele-saree - and its working properly)

Then I made some other methods in that class controller as follows:

```
public function pg1() {
    //page and data load here
}
```

Then goes to route and created url for that with following code:

```
$route['Priyamani-saree-images'] = "celeSaree_c/pg1";
```

(This code gave me url `"localhost/mysite/Priyamani-saree-images"` - Which working fine as I want)

But I want url as `"localhost/mysite/cele-saree/Priyamani-saree-images"` and for that I used following code:

```
$route['cele-saree/Priyamani-saree-images'] = "celeSaree_c/pg1";
```

(When I goes to `"localhost/mysite/cele-saree/Priyamani-saree-images"` I got all content properly but found that 
its stylesheet source is changed:

```
"localhost/mysite/assets/cele_saree/css/cele_saree.css"
```

to

```
"localhost/mysite/cele-saree/assets/cele_saree/css/cele_saree.css"
```

which causing error 404.

Same thing is happend with internal images also.)

I have set base_url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/mysite/';
```

Please guide me what to do regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinions, for `image/css/javascript` I preferred to get the resources by calling this way:

```
"/assets/cele_saree/css/cele_saree.css"
 ^
 |

This slash will call from root path
```

instead of using `base_url()` like

```
"localhost/mysite/assets/cele_saree/css/cele_saree.css"
```

**Example:**

```
<link href="/assets/cele_saree/css/cele_saree.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<img src="/assets/cele_saree/images/sample_image.png" />
```

> For your case, if you want to change the `routes` based on your
>   convenience it will not effect the source path.

Comment: Can you explain me where this should be added and how?

Comment: @MasterProns I've modifed my answer.

Comment: I have did same thing but causing this issue if have any other way please tell it.